# I have a Validation error in my Django models.py file

Tags: python, django

I am making a table in Django with the models.py file and when I run the code it gives a validation error which goes like this:

```
        django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“null” value must be either True or False.']
```

this is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models


class Users:
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    birthday = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    terms_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have tried commenting out the fields with boolean values along with singling out each line to see if it produces the error

Comment: try add `blank=True` parameter for `BooleanField`

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan 
it still returned the same error

Comment: He you try `null=False`?